# How to get over 200 records from zoho server via ZCRMSDK in Net core?

Tags: api, sdk, crm, zoho

I have get all records from zoho api via .net. When I call `module.getrecords();` ZohoCRM returned last 200 records, but I need all.

```
var response = module.GetRecords();
List<ZCRMRecord> records = response.BulkData;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get module records over 200 records using ZOHO CRM APIs :**

This time, You can't access over 200 records with a request and get maximum 200 records with each request and insert, update or delete maximum 100 records with each request.

These are **ZOHO** APIs limitations. If in future, the **ZOHO** updates records limitation to get records from APIs then you can access.

And alternate solution is that if you want to get maximum records then you can get records one by one and hold & merge new geted data with previous data list.

> https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads?sort_order=desc&sort_by=Created_Time&page=1&per_page=200

You can call this url one by one with page incremented value using web request with hold previous data then it will be possible otherwise not.

To click on following link for more information about **ZOHO CRM APIs** limitation.

[API Limit](https://www.zoho.com/developer/help/api/api-limits.html)